# AWS Fargate vs Lambda with Provisioned concurrency

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-fargate

I want to support a light-weight functionality (a DDB lookup and forward the request to backend service) supporting around peak 50 TPS with an acceptable latency <1s, I was thinking about using lambda with provisioned concurrency feature, or is it better to use Fargate?

When should we prefer Fargate to Lambda with Provisioned concurrency feature?

Any pointers to cost, performance study of both the services is helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general I would prefer Lambda over Fargate for the following reasons:

1. Scaling is handled for you. This can be particularly important if your traffic is very spiky and unpredictable.
2. At low volume you might not have to pay anything
3. It's easier to deploy and configure

Fargate does have some advantages, however.

1. At a higher load you may find that Fargate is cheaper.
2. A single Fargate task may be able to handle quite a few requests, so you might not need a lot of scaling. This depends a lot on language and what the code does.
3. No cold starts. Whilst provisioned concurrency in Lambda helps with this it doesn't deal with traffic spikes. If you have consistent/known spikes in traffic you can probably handle it with autoscaling in Fargate.

There is more that goes into it that what I've stated, and I've certainly over simplified some of my statements, but it's a good starting place.

Comment: While that’s true the question specifically asked about lambda with provisioned concurrency, so they won’t ever have the “zero” state.